# Concatenating multiple URLs to create new page URLs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I pasted the following URLs into a spreadsheet:

```
https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?google_chrome_workaround&page=1&category_id=9&sort=magic
https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?google_chrome_workaround&page=2&category_id=9&sort=magic
https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?google_chrome_workaround&page=3&category_id=9&sort=magic
```

And I want it to generate the rest of the links (pages) by changing the number in &page= to &page=4, &page=5 etc.

How do I do this in Microsoft Excel?

I tried selecting all three cells and dragging the bottom right corner, but it results in the same URLs (pages 1, 2 and 3) being repeated over and over. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seperating the first part of the string into column A, the page number in column B and then the remainder of the string in column C, you can copy them down to as many as pages you need.

[image]

Then in another column use the following formula to put it back together.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)
```

Drag this formula down as many rows as you need. You will then have all the URLs for the pages.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so now I not only have a solution but learned what "concatenate" actually means. Thanks for the answer and for taking the time to include the screenshots!

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted so the question will show as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Break it up into 3 columns and then concatenate it back together in the fourth column:

```
"https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?google_chrome_workaround&page="
1
"&category_id=9&sort=magic"
=a1&b1&c1
```

Drag down all 4 columns and the numbered column should increment automatically as you expect.